# Remove duplicate files from IIS for same application

Tags: iis

I have X the same applications in IIS(some code/exe, but different config file).
Would it be possible to put duplicate files to some folder?

For example I have applications:

```
Canada.weather.com
usa.weather.com
mexico.weather.com
```

Uses same .dll and .exe, but have different config.

Comment: No. In general that's not possible. Even if they come from the same source code, you should try to keep them separate. Messing up IIS configuration system with location tags can only lower maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex says, we don't suggest you to put duplicate files to some folder. If one of the dll is missed or not, it will make all the sites down.

If you still want to do this , you could apply the setting in applicationHost.config and wrapping it in a  tag.

The applicationhost.config file path :

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

Each sites will have its own location, you could add the custome configuration inside each location tag.

Like belowl, I enable the windows auth for "BrandoTestSite":

```
<location path="BrandoTestSite">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Notice: This way is lower maintainability. We don't suggest you choose this way to manage mutiple application.